# Stuck with pytube

Tags: python, pytube

Oh my python guys, please help me.
One of my python projects suddenly stopped working for no reason.
I'm using pytube module and when i try to run the code i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\search.py", line 94, in fetch_and_parse
    sections = raw_results['contents']['twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer'][
KeyError: 'twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer'                                                                             fetch_and_parse

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giova\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\youtubeapp.py", line 38, in <module>
    videoSearch()
  File "C:\Users\giova\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\youtubeapp.py", line 21, in videoSearch
    availableResults = len(vid.results)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\search.py", line 62, in results
    videos, continuation = self.fetch_and_parse()                                                                      results
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\search.py", line 97, in fetch_and_parse                                                                                                       fetch_and_parse
    sections = raw_results['onResponseReceivedCommands'][0][
KeyError: 'onResponseReceivedCommands'
```

This is not even the only error i get, sometimes i got "http error 410: gone" error or some like this. I haven't changed the code for about two weeks (it was working two weeks ago) and it stopped working. I don't know what is happening to my code.

This is the full code:

```
from pytube import Search, YouTube

print("================================\n What do you want to do?: ")

availableChoose = [
    '1 Search videos', 
    '...', 
    '================================'
]

for choose in availableChoose:
    print(choose)

userChoose = input()

userChoose = userChoose.lower()

def videoSearch():
    userSearch = input("Enter the title of the video you want to search: ")
    vid = Search(userSearch)
    availableResults = len(vid.results)
    strAvailableResults = str(availableResults)
    print("The available results are " + strAvailableResults)
    vidResultsList = vid.results
    vidResultsList = str(vidResultsList)
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace("<pytube.__main__.YouTube object: videoId=", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace(">", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace("[", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace("]", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace(" ", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.split(',')
    for vidResultsObject in vidResultsList:
        vidLink = ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + vidResultsObject)
        vidTempObject = YouTube(vidLink)
        print(vidTempObject.title + " - " + vidLink)
        
if(userChoose == "search" or userChoose == "search video" or userChoose == "search videos" or userChoose == "1"):
    videoSearch()
```

Comment: Your [`410 GONE` is already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813042/pytube-is-not-working-properly-in-python-3-9) and else ... nothing malfunctioning, just some video vanished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pytube's 11.0.0 API docs list the [Search.`fetch_and_parse()`](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.contrib.search.Search.fetch_and_parse) method.

The corresponding [source-code](https://pytube.io/en/latest/_modules/pytube/contrib/search.html?highlight=onResponseReceivedCommands#) shows that it internally handles a KeyError for `onResponseReceivedCommands`:

```py
 # Initial result is handled by try block, continuations by except block
        try:
            sections = raw_results['contents']['twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer'][
                'primaryContents']['sectionListRenderer']['contents']
        except KeyError:
            sections = raw_results['onResponseReceivedCommands'][0][
                'appendContinuationItemsAction']['continuationItems']
```

This method is an inner one, that is used by your `vid.results` call.

Might be, that the Youtube API has changed there response and your version of pytube is not fitting anymore.

### Bug already filed

See pytube [issue #1082](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1082) and [issue #1106](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1106).

### Meanwhile use another branch

[*tfdahlin*'s fork has a bugfixed version](https://github.com/tfdahlin/pytube/tree/bugfixes). It was already proposed as Pull-Request to the project:

- [PR #1090](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/pull/1090), opened on 2021-08-13 (currently waiting for approval).

Comment: so, what should i do with my code? i tried to use fetch_and_parse() method, succesfully upgraded pytube to 11.0 but still not working, i wonder where is the problem. I also tried to run a similar code line by line in the cmd and it seems the error is in the vid.results method, that suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @amuchinandthelens Sorry, unfortunate updates: It's a bug waiting for a new release. Meanwhile you can clone or download the _bugfixes_ branch linked and try to use this. Or search for `pip install from git repo` and find a way to install python-packages directly from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling to get around the search results provided by pytube Search module. Since search results are looking like objects, I was thinking (lazily) that I cannot convert the object list in to strings.

After modifying your function as below, the results are printed as youtube links.
'''

```
def videoSearch(search_list): #provide the search.results list as input
    for result in search_list: #Begin video id extraction
        result = str(result)
        temp = result.replace("<pytube.__main__.YouTube object: videoId=", "")
        temp = temp.split(',')[0] #get the correct video id
        vidLink = ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + temp)
        print(vidLink)
```

'''
Try it out.